# Change type of control by type

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, types

I'm having following problem.
I should convert a control to a certain type, this can be multiple types
 
(for example a custom button or a custom label, ....)
Here's an example of what i would like to do:

```
private void ConvertToTypeAndUseCustomProperty(Control c)
{
     Type type = c.getType();
     ((type) c).CustomPropertieOfControl = 234567;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although C#, before 4.0, doesn't support dynamic type resolution as VB does, it can be achieved with a little bit of reflection.

```
private void ConvertToTypeAndUseCustomProperty(Control c) 
{ 
   PropertyInfo p = c.GetType().GetProperty("CustomPropertieOfControl"); 
   if (p == null)
     return;
   p.SetValue(c, new object[] { 234567 }); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it fair to assume that you control the types which have "CustomPropertyOfControl"? If so, make them all implement an interface, and cast to that interface.

The point of a cast is to tell the compiler something you know that it doesn't - *at compile time*. Here you don't know the type at compile time. If you know some base class or interface, then you can tell the compiler *that* with no problem.

Now in C# 4 you *could* do this using dynamic typing:

```
private void ConvertToTypeAndUseCustomProperty(Control c)
{
    dynamic d = c;
    d.CustomPropertyOfControl = 234567;
}
```

However, even though you *can* do this, I'd still recommend sticking with static typing if at all possible - if you've got a group of types which all have some common functionality, give them a common interface.